# How would I group routes deno's oak framework?

Tags: middleware, deno, oak

The problem I currently have is, that I got some routes for my API that I want to group such for each route of that group, some authentication middleware can execute. Let's say I have a list of nodes, then my current implementation looks like this:

```
router
    .get('/nodes', authMiddleware, getNodes)
    .post('/node', authMiddleware, getNode)
    .get('/node/:id', authMiddleware, getSingleNode)
    .put('/node/:id', authMiddleware, updateNode)
```

Is there an shorter way for using the authMiddleware for each of this route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.use` method

```js
router.use(authMiddleware)
router
    .get('/nodes', getNodes)
    .post('/node', getNode)
    .get('/node/:id', getSingleNode)
    .put('/node/:id', updateNode)
```